# I have api in ajax format how can i code in android to get the response

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

I have api in ajax format ,how can i code in android to get access to server.I have API ID and API key and URL for access to server.
My api code is in the format

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.abc.com/server/api/user.login'
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        api_id: 4,
        api_key: '06875425-b293-43af-9966-1245125f6bb95b1f7c5e-f932-4916-87f5-db0b298f2',
        token: 'api_token_from_previous_call',
    },
    success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is jQuery.  Are you running that code from within a webview in your Android app or something?

Here are some quick thoughts:

If you need to hit your API from native Android code, I recommend Google's Volley library for making the network request.  You can [read about Volley here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), and this [video from last year's Google I/O](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) is a good intro to what it can do.

Once you get the response, you can use the Android [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class to work with it.

Comment: but I don't how to use above  API format in my android code using java